# uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I was upgrading version of rails from `6.0.4` to `7.0.1` I also upgraded some gems for the dependencies. After that when I start rails server an error pops out

```
1: from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/activeadmin-2.12.0/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:2:in `<main>' /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/activeadmin-2.12.0/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:3:in `\<module:ActiveAdmin\>': uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)
```

I made some changes in `gemfile`

## Admin

```
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "coffee-rails"
gem 'rails_admin', '\~\> 3.0.0'
gem 'activeadmin'#, '\~\> 2.12.0'
gem 'active_admin_role', '\~\> 0.2.1'
gem 'responsive_active_admin', '\~\> 0.0.6'
gem 'activeadmin_addons'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'inherited_resources', '\~\> 1.11'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution here. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/7196

in `config/initializers/active_admin_extensions.rb`

change this

```
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.send(:include, ActiveAdmin::CustomActions)
```

to

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_admin_controller) do
  ActiveAdmin::BaseController.include ActiveAdmin::CustomActions
end
```

PS: Your file name can be different

Comment: I don't have these file in my initializers these issue is arrising due to zeitwerk dependencies

Comment: Have you been able to fix this problem? If not try searching in your whole project if you are using the `ActiveAdmin:BaseController` anywhere. Your file name can be different.